# Extract 4 SSE integers to 4 chars

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

Suppose I have a `__m128i` containing 4 32-bit integer values.

Is there some way I can store it inside a `char[4]`, where the lower char from each `int` value is stored in a `char` value?

Desired result:

```
           r1          r2          r3          r4
__m128i    0x00000012  0x00000034  0x00000056  0x00000078

  |
  V

char[4]    0x12        0x34        0x56        0x78
```

SSE2 and below is preferred.
Compiling on MSVC++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SSE2 you can use the following code:

```
char[4] array;
x = _mm_packs_epi32(x, x);
x = _mm_packus_epi16(x, x);
*((int*)array) = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(x);
```

Comment: Should that not say `*(int*)` instead of just `(int*)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, with SSSE3 you can do it with only one shuffling operation using [`_mm_shuffle_epi8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531427.aspx). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167707/translating-sse-to-neon-how-to-pack-and-then-extract-32bit-result). You do consume one register more though, it depends on what is more important for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP wants this to work on SSE2, but yes, with SSSE3 it's much easier.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, I should have pointed out that was SSSE3, and I had missed that line from OP. Thanks!